# Are runtime bounds decidable for anything nontrivial?

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity

> **Problem**  Given a Turing machine $M$ which has known runtime ${O}(g(n))$ with respect to input length $n$, is the runtime of $M \in {O}(f(n))$?

Is the above problem decidable for some nontrivial pairs of $g$ and $f$?A solution is trivial if $g(n) \in O(f(n))$.

This is related to the problem [Are runtime bounds in P decidable? (answer: no)](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/5004/are-runtime-bounds-in-p-decidable-answer-no). One can derive from [Viola's answer](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/a/5006/314) that if $f(n)\not \in o(n)$ and $f(n)\not \in O(g(n))$ then the problem is undecidable.

The requirement that $f(n)\not \in o(n)$ is because the $M'$ in Viola's proof need $O(n)$ time to find its input size. Thus Viola's proof could not work when $f(n)=1$.

It would be interesting if we can decide on the run time of sublinear time algorithms. A special case is when we have arbitrary $g(n)$ and $f(n)=1$.

Comment: Since the question you link to was very well received on CSTheory, you might want to flag for migration later.

Comment: Somewhat late to the game here, but I've added a more complete answer.

Answer (score 7):

Here are a few remarks which could be relevant:

1. Kobayashi proved that a TM running in time $o(n\log n)$ accepts a regular language (and so runs in time $O(n)$); recently this has been extended to non-deterministic TMs ([Tadaki, Yamakami and Lin](http://arxiv.org/pdf/cs/0310046.pdf)).
2. Machines running in time $o(n)$ actually run in constant time (consider any $n$ for which the running time is less than $n$; adding characters to the end doesn't affect the TM).

Comment: it is worth pointing out that 1. holds for one-tape TMs only

Comment: In remark 1, how does it follow that, because a TM that accepts a regular language, it runs in time $O(n)$?  Of course, there is *another* TM that accepts the same language that runs in time $O(n)$.  But that doesn't seem to imply that the given TM runs in time $O(n)$.  Is it known that there is no TM that runs in time, say, $\Theta(n \log(n) / \log \log n)$?  Note that his has little to do with acceptance of any particular language.

Comment: [follow up] In turns out that Kobayashi's proof does essentially prove that any 1-tape TM running in time $o(n\log n)$ runs in time $O(n)$.  See the answer I posted for more info.

Answer (score 3):

There are a few related posts and papers (summarized down below), but they don't quite answer this particular question.
Here we mostly answer it.
Consider the problem for an arbitrary pair of functions $f$ and $g$.

**Theorem 1 (lower bounds).**
*For multi-tape TMs, the problem is either trivial or undecidable.*

*For 1-tape TMs, if $g(n) = \Omega(n\log n)$,
the problem is either trivial or undecidable.*

**Theorem 2 (upper bound).**
*For 1-tape TMs, if $g(n) = o(n\log n)$,
the problem is decidable.*

The one main non-trivial decidable case
is for 1-tape TMs when $g(n) = n$ and $f(n) = 1$.

The cases we leave open are for 1-tape TMs when $g$ is
"ill-behaved" in that $g$ is neither $O(n\log n)$ nor $\Omega(n \log n)$, in other words, $\lim\inf \frac{g(n)}{n\log n} = 0$
and $\lim\sup \frac{g(n)}{n\log n} = \infty$.

---

Here are the decision problems we consider:

- $H_{fg}$: *Given a multi-tape TM $M$ that runs in time $O(g(n))$,
  does $M$ run in time $O(f(n))$?*
- $H^1_{fg}$: *Given a single-tape TM $M$ that runs in time $O(g(n))$,
  does $M$ run in time $O(f(n))$?*

Say that $H_{fg}$ is *trivial* unless

- some TM $M$ that runs in time $O(g(n))$ also runs in time $O(f(n))$,
- and some TM $M$ that runs in time $O(g(n))$ doesn't run in time $O(f(n))$.

Likewise for $H^1_{fg}$, but restricting "TM"s to 1-tape TMs.

The proof of Theorem 1
reduces the Halting problem to $H_{fg}$ and $H^1_{fg}$,
similarly to several previous results,
but with some new tricks
to make sure the reduction produces a TM running in time $O(g(n))$.
Theorem 2 follows easily from known upper bounds.

---

#### Related work

Before we sketch the proofs, here is a summary of some related results.
Note that OP's question has two distinctive properties:
(i) it is about a *promise* problem
(the given TM must run in $O(g(n))$ time),
and (ii) it asks whether the TM runs in time $O(f(n))$.
Most of the results published in traditional venues below
are promise-free,
and many concern *exact* (not big-$O$) bounds.
The stack-exchange posts do consider promise problems.
Informally, having a strong promise (small $g$),
or having exact (as opposed to big-$O$) bounds for $f$
tends to reduce the computational complexity of $H_{fg}.$

It is an easy exercise to show that
the problem "*Given a TM $M$, does $M$ run in time $O(1)$?"*
is undecidable,
whereas "*Given a TM $M$ and a constant $c$,
does $M$ run in time at most $c$?*"
is decidable.

- For many interesting functions $f(n)$ (e.g. $f(n) = n+1$)
  it is not decidable whether a given *multi-tape* TM
  runs in time $f(n)$ (note no $O$-notation!)
  [[Hájek, 1979](https://doi.org/10.1016/0304-3975(79)90046-X)].
- Any of the following properties guarantees that the language of a given 1-tape TM $M$ is regular:

> 1. $M$ is deterministic and runs in time $O(n)$
>    [[Hennie, 1965](https://doi.org/10.1016/S0019-9958(65)90399-2)],
> 2. $M$ is deterministic and runs in time $(o(n\log n))$
>    [[Hartmanis, 1968](https://doi.org/10.1145/321450.321464)],
> 3. $M$ is non-deterministic with all execution paths running in time $(o(n\log n))$
>    [[Kobayashi, 1985](https://doi.org/10.1016/0304-3975(85)90165-3)].

- From the proofs of those results it more or less follows that every 1-tape TM running in time $o(n\log n)$ runs in time $O(n)$
  [[Gajser, 2015](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.tcs.2015.07.028)],
  and that, given any linear function $f(n)$,
  it is decidable
  whether a given 1-tape TM runs in time $f(n)$
  (note the absence of big-$O$ here!)
  [[Gajser, 2019](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jcss.2019.08.004)].
  (In fact Gajser shows this is in co-NP.)
- Given a TM whose run-time is promised to be bounded by some (unknown) polynomial, one cannot compute an explicit polynomial bound
  [[Math Overflow, 2010](https://mathoverflow.net/q/28056/27773)].
  Similarly, given such a TM and integer $k$,
  it is undecidable whether the TM runs in time $O(n^k)$
  [[CS Theory stack-exchange, 2011](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/a/5006/8237)].
  The latter post cites
  [[Hartmanis, 1989](https://doi.org/10.1137/1.9781611970395)]
  as covering similar material.

---

---

---

#### Utility lemma

Both proofs use the following utility lemma.

**Lemma 1.**
*If $H_{fg}$ or $H^1_{fg}$ is not trivial,
then $f(n) = \Omega(1)$ and $g(n) = \Omega(n)$.*

*Proof.*
Assume $H_{fg}$ is not trivial.
Some TM runs in time $O(f(n))$, so $f(n)$ and $g(n)$ are $\Omega(1)$.
Let $t(n)$ be the run time of some TM
such that $t(n)$ is $O(g(n))$ but not $O(f(n))$.
As observed in e.g. Lemma 3.1 [Gajser, 2015]
if $t(n_0) \le n_0$ for any $n_0$,
then it must be that $t(n) = O(1) = O(f(n))$
(because on inputs of size $n_0$
the TM's tape head never leaves the input,
so the TM also halts in at most $n_0$ steps on any larger input).
So $g(n)$ must be $\Omega(n)$.
This proves Lemma 1 for $H_{fg}$.
The same proof (but restricted to 1-tape TMs) works for $H^1_{fg}$
$~~~\Box$

#### Proof sketch for Theorem 1

First consider $H_{fg}$.
Assume $H_{fg}$ is not trivial.
Let $M_g$ be a TM with run-time in $O(g(n))$ but not $O(f(n))$.
Our goal is to make the natural reduction from the Halting problem to $H_{fg}$ work.  Given a 1-tape DTM $M$, the reduction outputs a $2$-tape DTM $M'$ that does the following:

TM $M'$ on input $x$ of length $n=|x|$:

> 1. simulate $M$ on empty input until it halts or completes some $\Theta(n)$ steps, whichever comes first
> 2. if $M$ doesn't halt during that simulation, then simulate $M_g$ on input $x$ until $M_g$ halts

The implementation will ensure that the run time of $M'$ is always $O(g(n))$, and is $O(f(n))$ if and only if $M$ halts.

###### Implementation details and proof of correctness for $H_{fg}$

Step 1 holds $x$ on its first tape
while using its second tape to simulate $M$.
Meanwhile, just before each simulated step of $M$,
Step 1 moves the head of the first tape one cell to the right
(thus using this head as a counter).
Step 1 halts the simulation when $M$ halts
or when the head of the first tape moves off of $x$.
Step 1 then returns the head of the first tape to cell 1 of that tape.
Step 2 of $M'$ then simulates $M_g$ on input $x$ using just the first tape.
This completes the reduction.

To see that it's correct,
first consider the case that $M$ halts on empty input,
in some $h$ steps.  Note that $h=O(1)$, that is, it is independent of $x$.
Step 1 of $M'$ then runs in time $O(\min(h, n)) = O(1)$.
Step 2 of $M'$ only runs if $n\le h = O(1)$,
so runs in time $O(\max_{n \le h} g(n)) = O(1)$.
So, in the case that $M$ halts on empty input, $M'$ runs in time $O(1)$.
By Lemma 1 this is $O(f(h))$ and $O(g(h))$.
So, if $M$ halts on empty input, then $M'$ runs in time $O(f(h))$
and $O(g(h))$.

Next consider the case that $M$ never halts.
Step 1 of $M'$ takes $O(n=|x|)$ time.
Step 2 then takes $O(g(n))$ time.
So $M'$ runs in time $O(g(n) + n)$.
By Lemma 2 this is $O(g(n))$.
So, if $M$ doesn't halt on empty input, then $M'$ runs in time $O(g(n))$.

So $M$ always runs in time $O(g(n))$,
and runs in time $O(f(n))$ iff $M$ halts on empty input.
So the reduction is correct in the case $k\ge 2$.
This proves Theorem 1 for this case.

###### Implementation details and proof of correctness for $H^1_{fg}$

Assume $H^1_{fg}$ is not trivial.
Assume (per the theorem statement) that
$g(n) = \Omega(n\log n).$
The proof is the same as for $H_{fg}$,
except that $M'$ implements Step 1 differently, as follows,
using only the one available tape.

Step 1 of $M'$ will simulate $M$,
meanwhile counting the number $t$ of simulated steps,
and somehow detecting when (if) $t$ reaches $\Omega(n)$.
The challenge is to do such a simulation with a slowdown of
at most an $O(\log n)$ factor.
That is, $M'$ should simulate the first $t$ steps of $M$
in $O(t \log t)$ time.

Throughout the simulation, we think of $M'$
as having three virtual tapes, sharing one common tape head.
The first virtual tape holds $x$.
This virtual tape is read-only during Step 1.
The second virtual tape is used as the simulated tape of $M$.
The third tape is used as a "work" tape for $M'$
to hold additional state as described below.
(Each tape cell is initialized lazily, only when,
in the course of the computation as described below,
$M'$ encounters the cell.  These virtual cells are implemented
by introducing appropriate symbols into the tape alphabet of $M'$ in a standard way.)

As $M'$ simulates $M$, it stores on its work tape,
just to the right of the tape head,
a counter that holds the number $t$
of steps simulated so far.
It encodes $t$ in binary, using $O(\log t)$ bits.
Each time $M'$ simulates a step of $M$,
it also increments $t$.
Each increment takes $O(\log t)$ time,
including the time to reposition $t$
to keep it just to the right of the tape head.
This effectively slows  the simulation by an $O(\log t)$ factor.

Also, each time $t$ passes a power of two, $M'$ pauses the simulation temporarily and does a *probe*.
The probe moves the tape head $t$ steps to the right,
looking for the end of the original input $x$.
If it finds the end within $t$ steps,
it knows that $n= \Theta(t)$,
so it stops the simulation
(and restores the tape to its original state for Step 2).

In order to look $t$ steps to the right,
as $M'$ moves the tape head to the right,
it brings along a "countdown" value $t'$,
encoded in binary and held just to the right of the tape head.
The probe initializes $t'=t$,
then, with each step to the right,
decrements $t'$ and shifts it one step to the right.
If $t'$ reaches zero before the probe finds
the end of $x$, the probe stops
and returns the head to resume the simulation of $M$.
Note that probing $t$ cells to the right in this way
takes time $O(t\log t)$.

This completes the description of $M'$.
Next we verify that the reduction is correct.

Using the probes,
$M'$ ensures that $t = O(n)$ throughout the simulation,
and that the simulation halts when $t = \Theta(n)$.

A probe (after $t$ simulated steps) takes $O(t\log t)$ steps.
So the total time for $M'$ to simulate the first $t$ steps of $M$ is at most:

$$\begin{align}
&O(t \log t) 
&& \text{for simulating the } t \text{ individual steps, plus} \\ 
&+O(t \log t + \frac{t}{2} \log \frac{t}{2} + \frac{t}{4}\log \frac{t}{4} + \cdots)
&& \text{for the } {\log_2 t} \text{ probes, making}   \\
&=O(t\log t) 
&& \text{total.}
\end{align}$$

Suppose that $M$ halts on empty input, in, say, some $h$ steps.
So $h=O(1)$ (independent of $x$).
There are $O(2^h) = O(1)$ inputs of length $O(h)$,
so the time for those is $O(1)$.
For inputs with length $n = \Omega(h)$,
the simulation will stop when $M$ halts,
so will take time $O(h \log h) = O(1)$.
Step 2 then does nothing.
So, if $M$ halts, then $M'$ runs in time $O(h\log h) = O(1)$.
This is $O(f(n))$ and $O(g(n))$ (as required) by Lemma 1.
So the reduction is correct in this case.

In the case that $M$ never halts,
Step 1 of $M'$ stops the simulation after $O(n)$ steps,
so Step 1 takes $O(n\log n)$ time.
Step 2 then takes $O(g(n))$ time.
So in this case $M'$ takes time $O(n\log n + g(n))$.
By assumption $g(n) = \Omega(n\log n)$,
so this is $O(g(n))$.
So the reduction is correct in this case.
This proves Theorem 1. $~~~~\Box$

#### Proof sketch for Theorem 2

Assume per the theorem statement that $g(n) = o(n\log n)$.
By e.g. [Gajser, 2015] and Lemma 1,
any 1-tape TM running in time $o(n\log n)$
runs either in time $\Theta(1)$ or time $\Theta(n)$.
Also, $f(n) \ne O(g(n))$ (else the problem is trivial).
So assume WLOG that $f(n) = \Theta(1)$ and $g(n) = \Theta(n)$.

By a result of [Gajser, 2019],
given any constant $a \ge 1$ and 1-tape TM $M$,
it is decidable whether $M$ finishes in at most $cn$
steps (on all $n$, for all inputs of length $n$).
Further, given a 1-tape TM that runs in time at most $cn$,
one can explicitly compute, from $M$ and $c$,
a DFA $D$ such that the language of $D$
contains exactly the sequences of crossing sequences
that represent accepting computations of $M.$

(Each crossing sequence has length $O(1)$.
The symbols in the input alphabet for $D$
correspond to pairs $(\alpha, s)$,
where $\alpha$ is an input symbol for $M$,
and $s$ is a possible crossing sequence.)

Finally, here is the procedure for deciding,
given a 1-tape TM $M$ that runs in time $O(g(n)) = O(n)$,
whether $M$ runs in time $O(f(n)) = O(1)$:

1. Compute a $c$ such that $M$ runs in time $c n$.
   (Use Gajser's result with $c=1,2,\ldots$
   to find the smallest such $c$.)
2. From $M$ and $c$,
   use Gajser's other result
   to compute a DFA $D$ such that the language of $D$
   contains exactly those sequences
   that represent computations of $M$.
3. Return 'yes' (i.e., that $M$ runs in time $O(f(n))$) if $L(D)$ is finite, else return 'no'.  (This is decidable given $D$.)
   $~~~~\Box$